# Record creation being rolled back without explanation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model

I have a model "User" that up until now didn't have any issues. I added some validations and noticed that I no longer could add any new Users - the record would be rolled back. So I removed the validations, but my records were still being rolled back. So I eliminated literally all the code from my model file so all it contains is this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

but I'm still getting the same error.

In my rails console:

```
> User.create(name: "test")
  (0.6ms) BEGIN
  (2.3ms) ROLLBACK
#=> #<User id: nil, name: "test", (et cetera)>
```

I don't even know how to start figuring out what's wrong. How can I even debug this? All my other models work normally.

This is what I added before this started:

```
blacklist = ['home'].freeze
validates :name, exclusion: {in: blacklist}
```

**SOLVED:**

I integrated Devise with this model, so there were some validations in place that weren't in my Devise.rb file. I had to run `@user.errors` to get back the errors that were preventing the record from being saved.

Comment: try this `User.create!(name: "test")`

Comment: You can always check if the record is valid or not with `.valid?` and `.errors` will return you the errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
user = User.new(name: "test")
user.save

user.errors  # This should contain the errors that prevented your object from being saved.
```